# c++ condition variable shared_mutex

Tags: c++, c++17

Let's say I got the following code:

```
std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> sl;
std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> ul;
std::condition_variable_any cv;
```

And I need to wait for some condition. How can I lock `sl` when I inspect that condition. Only when that condition is true, I lock `ul` and check that condition again?

Comment: can you post a bit more contextual code that demonstrates the requirement? it looks like this might be an XY problem.

Comment: @RichardHodges I'm just curious

Comment: You can't lock ul while you have sl, and you can't release sl during your predicate, so you're stuck here. you need a different design.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `upgrade_lock`.  It was proposed, but the committee rejected it: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3568.html#OverviewUpgrade